# JavaFX: expanding TextArea, Listview (Vgrow/Hgrow = 'ALWAYS' doesn't work)

Tags: java, listview, javafx, textarea

I have a simple JavaFX application, a BorderLayout with an AnchorPane and inside two panes, one contains a HBox and a VBox with a TextArea and a ListView. I would like them to increase in width, as I increase the window size. I have tried Vgrow/Hgrow = 'ALWAYS' and Max Width/Max Height = 'MAX_VALUE' on the the controls but nothing works.- (I use Scene Builder to create the fxml)

[image]

The FXML is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Pane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
            <Pane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="200.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <children>
                              <TextArea maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                              <ListView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

My java application class (HelloApplication):

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I removed the unnecessary AnchorPane and other Panes, kept only a VBox and placed it in another BorderLayout, take a look, now seems perfect :)

[image]

Comment: don't hard-code sizing constraints ..

Comment: As well as not hard-coding the sizes (what are you expecting to happen if you, for example, hard-code the preferred height of the `HBox` to `200`?), don't use layout panes that essentially rely on hard-coded sizes. These include `AnchorPane` and `Pane`. For the specific example you have, get rid of both `Pane`s and the `AnchorPane` and place the `HBox` directly in the center of the `BorderPane`. You may also be able to get rid of the `HBox`, since it has only one child node, and place the `VBox` directly in the center.

Comment: Dear @James_D can you write it as an answer, your comment solved my issue and I would like to vote it up and mark as an answer! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't hard-code sizes, and don't use layout panes such as `Pane` and `AnchorPane` that rely on hard-coded sizes except in very rare circumstances.

(You may sometimes need to set the max size to `Double.MAX_VALUE` to allow a control to grow beyond its preferred size, but even that is not necessary in this example, as far as I can tell.)

Your FXML has an empty `Pane` and at least two redundant wrapper containers which only wrap one node (the other `Pane` and the `AnchorPane`). Remove all of these and the hard-coded values and it will work:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <HBox>
            <children>
                <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <TextArea VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <ListView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Depending on your real use-case, you may not need the `HBox` either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
            <VBox>
                <children>
                    <TextArea VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    <ListView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                </children>
            </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```